# android XML parsers don't parse the complete link

Tags: android, xml-parsing

So, I've been working on parsing a XML file getting from the internet (RSS).

I've been working according to IBM's parsers that can be found [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/).

unfortunately, when I try to parse the link that look like this:

http://www.website.net/index.php?option=com_adsmanager&page=display&catid=87&tid=208196

but my parsers only show the link as: http://www.website.net/index.php?option=, and the rest of the link is getting cut off.

any thoughts on how to fix this?

***edit 1:***

the SaxParser even doesn't work at all. it claims (incorrectly) that the document is not well formed, but I know its not true since it was checked and doubled checked.

***edit 2:***

the `NodeList` had more than one child and every ampersand (&) created a new node.

therefor, the code I had:

```
if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(LINK)) {
    val = property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
    message.setLink(val);
}
```

was not good. and so, I fixed it to this code:

```
if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(LINK)) {
    val = "";
    NodeList list = property.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        val += list.get(i).getNodeValue().toString();
    }
    message.setLink(val);
}
```

that was the way to do this in the DOM XML feed parser. now all I have to do is find out a way to do this within a different parser from the IBM examples.

Comment: Some code will help us help you.

Comment: Is the RSS file valid xml? I.e. is the ampersands in the url `&amp;` or wrapped in `CDATA` in the `<link>` tag?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev, the code is in the link to IBM, I'm not using anything else.

@AndersLindahl, the RSS is valid and the links look like this: `<link>http://www.website.net/index.php?option=com_adsmanager&page=display&catid=87&tid=208196</link>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link>http://www.website.net/index.php?option=com_adsmanager&page=display&catid‌​=87&tid=208196</link>
```

...is not valid XML, since the `&`s are not followed by valid [xml entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML).

There are a couple of ways to work around this:

**Escape the `&`s**:

```
<link>http://www.website.net/index.php?option=com_adsmanager&amp;page=display&amp;catid‌​=87&amp;tid=208196</link>
```

**Wrap the `link` section in [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA)**

```
<link><![CDATA[http://www.website.net/index.php?option=com_adsmanager&page=display&catid‌​=87&tid=208196]]></link>
```

If you are not in control of the RSS file creation, you will have to pre-process the document before feeding it to an XML parser. Move forgiving xml parsers like [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/)  might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I sort of solved this.

my second update was a correct look at the problem.
the `NodeList` had more than one child and every ampersand (&) created a new node.

therefor, the code I had:

```
if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(LINK)) {
    val = property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
    message.setLink(val);
}
```

was not good. and so, I fixed it to this code:

```
if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(LINK)) {
    val = "";
    NodeList list = property.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        val += list.get(i).getNodeValue().toString();
    }
    message.setLink(val);
}
```

that was the way to do this in the DOM XML feed parser